# how android system knows the minSdk of an app without uses-sdk in manifest file

Tags: android

While decompiling and checking my app with apktool I found that there is no uses-sdk tag in manifest file.How android system is able to detect the android minimum version and target version the app supports at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***there is  `uses-sdk` but when decompile code its avilable in `apktool.yml` file***

check `apktool.yml` file where you have decompile code its look like

```
version: 1.5.2
apkFileName: pt.yourpackage.apk
isFrameworkApk: false
usesFramework:
  ids:
  - 1
sdkInfo:
  minSdkVersion: '7'
  targetSdkVersion: '15'
packageInfo:
  cur_package: pt.yourpackage.apk
  orig_package: pt.yourpackage.apk
compressionType: false
```

Comment: yes I found the minVersion in yml file thank you so much